# sum of values larger than the current value, and across different groups

Tags: r

I have the following data about trees:

```
DT <- data.table(id=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"),
                 species=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                 size=(1:9))

> DT
   id species size
1:  a       1    1
2:  b       1    2
3:  c       1    3
4:  d       2    4
5:  e       2    5
6:  f       2    6
7:  g       3    7
8:  h       3    8
9:  i       3    9
```

**For each tree, how can I calculate the sum of the sizes of all bigger trees & belonging to a particular species?**

Thanks to the answer to my previous question at [slow function by groups in data.table r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55263291/slow-function-by-groups-in-data-table-r) I can quickly calculate the sum of the sizes of all trees bigger than each tree using `cumsum()`: `size_larger` in the below data.

I manually calculated `size_larger_sp2` as example: for each tree the sum of the all bigger trees & belonging only to species 2. I would need the same for `size_larger_sp1` and `size_larger_sp3` for all rows.

```
> DT
   treeID species size size_larger size_larger_sp2
1:      a       1    1          44              15
2:      b       1    2          42              15
3:      e       1    3          39              15
4:      c       2    4          35              11
5:      d       2    5          30               6
6:      h       2    6          24               0
7:      f       3    7          17               0
8:      g       3    8           9               0
9:      i       3    9           0               0
```

For trees of the same species, I can subset the dataset to only that species and use again `cumsum()`. For trees belonging to different species, I can think only of functions like doing subset of species 1 plus the target tree of species 2, use `cumsum()`, then repeat for each tree, then repeat for each species. The problem is that I have 100k+ trees in 2k+ groups with 4 different species and those functions are extremely slow.

Here [Sum values larger than the current value, by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63543800/sum-values-larger-than-the-current-value-by-group) there is the same problem but without calculating values across species/groups.

Thanks.

Comment: (1) What is a *"target tree"*? (2) If you think the code you used to generate `size_larger_sp2` is applicable in this discussion, why did you not include it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work-around:

```
DT[,size_sp2:=ifelse(species==2,size,0),by=id]
DT[, size_larger_sp2 := (cumsum(size_sp2) - size_sp2)]
```

results in:

```
    > DT
   id species size size_larger size_sp2 size_larger_sp2
1:  i       3    9           0        0               0
2:  h       3    8           9        0               0
3:  g       3    7          17        0               0
4:  f       2    6          24        6               0
5:  e       2    5          30        5               6
6:  d       2    4          35        4              11
7:  c       1    3          39        0              15
8:  b       1    2          42        0              15
9:  a       1    1          44        0              15
```